# Check Network Connection iPhone

Tags: iphone, networking, connection

I am developing app in iPhone which is fetch the data from website dynamically, I am checking whether Wifi and GPRS are connected but when wifi is not reachable, App crash.

I am using this method to check connection.

```
+ (BOOL) isConnected {  
    // Part 1 - Create Internet socket addr of zero
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddr;
    bzero(&zeroAddr, sizeof(zeroAddr));
    zeroAddr.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddr);
    zeroAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Part 2- Create target in format need by SCNetwork
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef target = 
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *) &zeroAddr);

    // Part 3 - Get the flags
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(target, &flags);

    // Part 4 - Create output
    NSString *sNetworkReachable;
    if (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)
        sNetworkReachable = @"YES";
    else
        sNetworkReachable = @"NO";

    NSString *sCellNetwork;
    if (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
        sCellNetwork = @"YES";
    else
        sCellNetwork = @"NO";


    // Get host entry info for given host
    struct hostent *remoteHostEnt = gethostbyname("google.com");
    if(remoteHostEnt == nil ) return NO;

    // Get address info from host entry
    struct in_addr *remoteInAddr = (struct in_addr *) remoteHostEnt->h_addr_list[0];

    // Convert numeric addr to ASCII string
    char *sRemoteInAddr = inet_ntoa(*remoteInAddr);

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithFormat:
                 @"Network Reachable: %@\n"
                 @"Cell Network: %@\n"
                 @"Remote IP: %s\n",
                 sNetworkReachable,
                 sCellNetwork,
                 sRemoteInAddr];


    // Add text
    [sCellNetwork release];
    [sNetworkReachable release];

    NSLog(@"Message:%@",s);

    return [sNetworkReachable isEqualToString:@"YES"];  
}
```

Thanks
Vadivelu

Answer (score 4):

Why mess with IP addresses? You can call `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName()` directly instead:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Search for the Reachability sample application on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)

There is also the Open Source [NPReachability](https://github.com/nickpaulson/NPReachability) class on GitHub which does the same thing but uses a block as a handler.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a hidden UIWebView and load a website to it. Then use methods from the UIWebView.h to detect, whether loading was successful or not.

Comment: There is no reason to do this. Apple already provide an API for checking network reachability.